# Fila encadeada em C

Tags: c

Eu preciso colocar "10 placas de carro" em uma lista encadeada, só que eu estou tendo problemas de colocar algo do tipo char nesse ponteiro, eu até usei a função `strcpy` mas está dando bugs...
`strcpy(f->no, placaCarro)`, onde `placaCarro` é do tipo char... então este é o problema, não sei se ficou muito claro, mas espero que consigam me ajudar...

```
  Fila *criaFila(char *placaCarro){
    Fila *f = (Fila*)malloc(sizeof(Fila));
    f->no = placaCarro; //essa linha da erro, tentei usar strcpy aqui e não deu ...
    f->proximo = NULL;

    return f;

  }
```

Eu quero colocar 10 placas de carros, e eu queria colocar elas em "nós" cada nó contendo uma placa, só que não sei como fazer isso...

codes.c:8:11: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] f->no = placaCarro; ^

Está dando esse erro por justamente não estar atribuindo o char para este ponteiro...

Comment: Wendel coloque todo seu código junto na pergunta e comente na linha onde está dando o erro

Comment: Qual a estrutura Fila? Por acaso o elemento no é um inteiro?

Comment: qual o bug que da no `strcpy` ? Como é inicializado esse `placaCarro` ? como é essa estrutura `Fila`?

Comment: Boa tarde Wendel, teria como postar o código com o main, a _struct_ e a sua função tentando ser executada? facilitaria bastamnte

Comment: Isso, posta a `struct` da `Fila`. O `f->no` precisa ser do tipo `char*` para a operação `f->no = placaCarro` dar certo.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seria interessante se você colocasse todo o seu código. Fiz um teste aqui e não obtive nenhum problema.

Precisamos entender se "no" é uma string ou um char? (char são guardados na memória como inteiros, strings utilizam ponteiros)

Fiz um código simples que funcionou:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct fila
{
    char *no;
    struct fila *proximo;
} Fila;


//seu código
Fila *criaFila(char *placaCarro){
    Fila *f = (Fila*)malloc(sizeof(Fila));
    f->no = placaCarro; //essa linha da erro, tentei usar strcpy aqui e não deu ...
    f->proximo = NULL;

    return f;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char placa[10] = "abcd";
    printf("%s\n", placa); //aparece 'abcd'
    Fila *fila = criaFila(placa);
    printf("%s\n", fila->no); //'aparece 'abcd'
    return 0;
}
```

Como pode ver, a variável placa é uma string e chamando a função com `*placa` eu passo 'abcde' e chamando com `placa` eu passo o endereço da variável na memória que será copiado pra `no`.

Se não te ajudou, posta o código todo pra gente poder entender.